# How do I stop toothpaste from piling up on the cover?

Tags: cleaning, personal-care, bathroom

I always have a problem with toothpaste. My whole family uses the same toothpaste tube. At the end of the week, there is this huge glob of hardened toothpaste stuck over the end of the tube.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Close the lid after each use.

Comment: Uh... eww. You all use the same tube?

Comment: Ya... I know! :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to prevent oxygen from reacting with the toothpaste. Usually people would just reapply the cap, but you could store in a ziplock bag or similar airtight container.